# How to play multi screen

Tags: poker-strategy

I read a lot of articles about pokers and how to be a professional poker player. Most of them say that you have to start playing STT 9 handed, 4 or 6 tables simultaneously. I try to follow this tip but I feel that I get confused with multiple screen opened and I'm not able to determinte my opponents style (Tight agressive, losse agressive etc) because everything happen very fast. My question is, How is the best approach to play multiple tournaments simultaneously?

Answer (score 6):

Time and practice. If you're used to only playing 1 table, you can't expect to go from 1 table to 6 tables just like that.

What I found for me to be the best solution (for myself anyway) was to start slow and set goals. On top of these I cannot recommend them enough, get a HUD.

**Starting Slow:**

You need to realise that playing multiple tables is tough, and is a quick way to blow through your bankroll if you're unprepared. I would recommend when you sit down to play open 1 table. After 30 minutes ask yourself how you feel you're playing, and be brutally honest. If you're confident you are playing well open another table.

Keep doing this every 30 minutes, opening a new table if you feel you're still playing well with what ever number of tables you have open.

The minute you feel the number of tables becomes too much for you to play well, close a table. Don't make excuses, just close it. Your entire session will suffer from it.

**Setting Goals:**

You won't go from 1 tabling to 10 tabling in a week. You just won't play well. What I recommend is to have a gradual goal over a few weeks of where you'd like to be.

Obviously I don't know how much you are playing, but lets just say you're playing 5 days a week for some short sessions of like 2/3 hours. I think a realistic goal here would be to set yourself the goal of being able to play 3/4 tables by the end of the week. Don't just reach the number of tables you want to play and go great I've done it. At the end of the week seriously look at your game, your winrate and be very honest with yourself and how you felt you handled the number of tables.

The main thing is to multitable well there is no universal best approach, you'll have to find what works for you, but my advice would be to take it slow, be honest with how you're handling the tables and put in the time. You will get there.

Comment: Another helpful thing when learning to play more tables is to do so at lower stakes than you normally play at.  It takes some pressure off and gives a little more room for error since you're basically experimenting.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with you here. Thanks for adding it. Overlooked on my part :)

Comment: Thank you guys... Help me a lot.. I will consider all of you thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I only ever multi-table and generally it is 5-8 tables

**Everybody struggles with playing too many tables, even the pros with the highest overall profit**. The reasons why are exactly the same as the ones you are struggling with.

It is a fact that SNE players and high volume players generally have a lower ROI than those playing lower volume. It's always a trade-off.

If your ROI with 5 tables is 20% and with 20 tables is 7%, well, it's arguably worth your while playing 20 tables instead of just 5 but it will be harder work.

I always advise any new player to use and familiarise themselves with an HUD. It is not just to help you play and plug leaks but more importantly it will give you indications of how your opponents are playing. It's pretty much impossible to go from 1 table to 5-10 tables and win without an HUD if you aren't already an expert poker player.

Once a poker player has assimilated the HUD info and become an expert player, I recommend they ditch the HUD.

The dangers of information overload are greater than the edge an HUD gives. I understand some pros always use an HUD but those HUDs are only useful against an unknown field if they use illegal software. To be of real use even against known players, your HUD has to have enough info to cover the average playing style of each opponent - one day a player might be very aggressive, another day passive. If the HUD only picks up on one of the styles employed, then rather than being useful, the HUD is a liability and eating your edge.

In answer to your question,

*"**How is the best approach to play multiple tournaments simultaneously?**"*

Stick to the number of tables at which you can make all your notes and assessments without giving yourself a headache. If this is only 1 or 2 tables to start, that's 100% fine. As it becomes easier and easier for you to see the info you want on 1-2 tables, you can then add a 3rd, and a 4th, etc, etc

Just remember that even for top-rated pros using HUDs, their ROI decreases with every table they add above 2-3 tables (for most experienced players it's actually easier to multi-table (2-3) than single table because it improves their interest/concentration)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel confortable with multiscreen setup, you should not play multitable. Multitabling is a matter of automating basic moves and setup. You need experience to automate most of your moves. Beside that, If you really want to progress, you should alway consider play on 2-4 tables maximum.

Also, don't multitable without a tracker. I can manage no tracker on 4 tables NL10 of fast poker because most of the people are bad. But once you go up you should reconsider the question because oponents adapte and exploit your leaks. You can't spoit your own leaks if you are multitabling (or you should do more session reviews).